# Is 'this php file' can be called or referred as HTTP API?

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, arduino

So I'm make an PHP file that used by Arduino to send coordinate to my database
In Arduino, there are GPS to get coordinate, relay to turn on/off LED, and SIM800L to send data over GPRS connection
When Arduino want to send data to my database, Arduino create http request by access

http://myserver.com/gprs?lat=-6.123&lng=100.123
gprs is a PHP file that created using codeigniter so there is not '.php' in the URL

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq6Qg.png)

The output when gprs.php is executed is 0 or 1. The 0 or 1 value is use to Arduino to control the relay. If output is 0, relay is on.. 1 relay is off..  The 0 or 1 value is received by relay_status table in mysql database...

So the gprs.php:
-> passing latitude and logitude to table coordinate in mysql database
(SQL like insert into bla bla bla)
-> querying the relay status
(SQL like Select column from relay_status)

Then, can gprs.php is called or referred as HTTP API. I'm looking in internet and found an API is usually generated JSON output, in my gprs.php file.. the output is not JSON output.

I want to know because I'm write an article or report about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API can return whatever you want it to return. While APIs usually return XML or JSON, you can let yours return whatever you want. Binary, a string, single digit responses - it's totally up to you. People mostly use JSON and XML because those are standardized formats which most other applications that call the API can easily read and process.

Basically, every PHP-Script can be an API. The difference between an API and a "normal" PHP script is the fact that an API returns only data, whereas a normal script returns a view.